# Change class members types based on template type, but not to the template type

Tags: c++, templates

I have a class that needs to be templated on some type A, and depending on the type then the member variables need to be changed, but not in a direct way based on A.

```
template <typename TypeA>
class A_class {
 public:
  A_class() {}
  A_class(TypeA a) : a_(a) {}
  void set_A(TypeA a) { a_ = a; }
  void A_fxn() { std::cout << "a = " << a_ << std::endl; }

 private:
  TypeA a_;

  // Here, I want somthing like the following:
  // If TypeA in an int, then TypeB is a double, and TypeC is a string.
  // If TypeA is a double, then TypeB is a string, and TypeC is an int.
  // If TypeA is a string, then TypeB is an int, and TypeC is a double.
  // etc...
  TypeB b_;
  std::vector<TypeC> c_;
};
```

Is there a way to do this?  Partial templates and conditionals seem like they might be the right answer, but I haven't been able to come up with a solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution:
Specialize the structure by TypeA and declare typedefs TypeB and TypeC inside

```cpp
template<typename>
struct choose_types;

template<>
struct choose_types<int> {
  using TypeB = double;
  using TypeC = std::string;
};

template<>
struct choose_types<double> {
  using TypeB = std::string;
  using TypeC = int;
};

template<>
struct choose_types<std::string> {
  using TypeB = int;
  using TypeC = double;
};
```

Usage:

```cpp
template <typename TypeA>
class A_class {
  using type_choice = choose_types<TypeA>;

public: // just for testing
  TypeA a_;
  typename type_choice::TypeB b_;
  std::vector<typename type_choice::TypeC> c_;
};

int main() {
  using A = A_class<int>;

  static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(A::b_), double>);
  static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(A::c_)::value_type, std::string>);

  using B = A_class<double>;

  static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(B::b_), std::string>);
  static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(B::c_)::value_type, int>);

  using C = A_class<std::string>;

  static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(C::b_), int>);
  static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(C::c_)::value_type, double>);
}
```

More 'hacky' way:

In this context, types are "looped", which means that it is possible to fasten a chain of types.
And then take the types from the chain in turn.

Code to make chain:

```cpp
template<typename... Ts>
struct type_holder{
    static constexpr auto value = sizeof...(Ts);
};

template<typename T>
struct just_type : type_holder<T> {
    using type = T;
};

using empty_pack = type_holder<>;

template<typename... Ts, typename... Us>
constexpr type_holder<Ts..., Us...> operator+(type_holder<Ts...>, type_holder<Us...>) {
    return {};
}

template<typename T, typename... Ts, std::size_t... Is>
constexpr std::size_t get_type_idx(type_holder<Ts...>, std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
    return (static_cast<std::size_t>(std::is_same_v<T, Ts> * Is) + ... + 0);
};

template<typename Is>
struct get_impl;


template<std::size_t... Is>
struct get_impl<std::index_sequence<Is...>> {
    template<typename T>
    static constexpr T dummy(decltype(Is, (void*)0)..., T*, ...);
};

template<std::size_t I, typename... Ts>
constexpr auto get(type_holder<Ts...>) {
    return just_type<decltype(get_impl<std::make_index_sequence<I>>::dummy(((Ts*)0)...))>{};
}

template<std::size_t I, typename T>
using get_t = typename decltype(get<I>(T{}))::type;

template<std::size_t Offset, typename... Ts, std::size_t... Is>
constexpr auto get_n_impl(type_holder<Ts...> t, std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
    return (empty_pack{} + ... + get<Offset + Is>(t));
}

template<std::size_t To, typename T>
using get_first_n_types = decltype(get_n_impl<0>(T{}, std::make_index_sequence<To>{}));

template<std::size_t From, typename T>
using get_last_n_types = decltype(get_n_impl<From>(T{}, std::make_index_sequence<T::value - From>{}));


template<typename T, typename TH>
struct make_chain_impl {
    static constexpr std::size_t type_idx = get_type_idx<T>(TH{}, std::make_index_sequence<TH::value>{});
    static constexpr std::size_t from = type_idx + 1;
    static constexpr std::size_t to = type_idx;

    using type = decltype(get_last_n_types<from, TH>{} + get_first_n_types<to, TH>{});
};
;
template<typename T, typename TH>
using make_chain = typename make_chain_impl<T, TH>::type;
```

Usage:

```
template<typename T, typename TH>
struct choose_types {
    using chain = make_chain<T, TH>;

    using TypeB = get_t<0, chain>;
    using TypeC = get_t<1, chain>;
};


using types = type_holder<int, double, std::string>;

template <typename TypeA>
class A_class {
  using type_choice = choose_types<TypeA, types>;

public:
  TypeA a_;
  typename type_choice::TypeB b_;
  std::vector<typename type_choice::TypeC> c_;
};

int main() {
  using A = A_class<int>;

  static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(A::b_), double>);
  static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(A::c_)::value_type, std::string>);

  using B = A_class<double>;

  static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(B::b_), std::string>);
  static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(B::c_)::value_type, int>);

  using C = A_class<std::string>;

  static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(C::b_), int>);
  static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(C::c_)::value_type, double>);
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/6h57oThEx)

Comment: So much code to basically reimplement `std::tuple`, `std::tuple_element`, and a couple additional things.

Comment: std::tuple and friends instantiate a lot of additional things on instantiation that are not needed, if you use tuple as type pack. 50 loc isn’t too much for c++

Comment: Thanks for this.  I ended up using your first, struct based version because in my more comple real world version the types weren't just a simple cycle.

Answer (score 2):

A concise solution to this particular problem would be:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

template <typename T> struct Cycle {};
template <> struct Cycle<int> {typedef double next;};
template <> struct Cycle<double> {typedef std::string next;};
template <> struct Cycle<std::string> {typedef int next;};

template <typename TypeA>
class A_class
{
  public:
  TypeA a_;
  typename Cycle<TypeA>::next b_;
  std::vector<typename Cycle<typename Cycle<TypeA>::next>::next> c_;
};

A_class<double> a;
static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(a.a_), double>::value);
static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(a.b_), std::string>::value);
static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(a.c_), std::vector<int>>::value);

int main() {return 0;}
```

Here, I've stripped away some members of your class that aren't strictly relevant and added an example usage with assertions at the end.

In this case, I used a helper class with [template specialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization) to accomplish the conditional logic you need. This ends up being relatively elegant because the type combinations you mentioned are cyclic permutations of each other. Use this kind of approach with caution, because in less friendly cases it can get very hairy very fast.

Answer (score 0):

```
// If TypeA in an int, then TypeB is a double, and TypeC is a string.
// If TypeA is a double, then TypeB is a string, and TypeC is an int.
// If TypeA is a string, then TypeB is an int, and TypeC is a double.
```

Turn this around and the conditionals basically write themselves:

```
// If TypeA is an int, then TypeB is a double, else if TypeA is a double, then TypeB is a string, else TypeB is an int
// If TypeA is an int, then TypeC is a string, else if TypeA is a double, then TypeC is an int, else TypeC is a double
```

For instance, here is `TypeB`:

```
using TypeB =
    std::conditional_t<std::is_same_v<TypeA, int>,
        double,
        std::conditional_t<std::is_same_v<TypeA, double>,
            std::string,
            int
        >
    >;
```

If you have N types `T1`, `T2`, ..., `TN` and `TypeA` is one of them, and you want `TypeB` to be the "next" one, and `TypeC` the one "after" `TypeB`, and so on where `T1` comes "after" `TN`, then you can do something like this:

```
template<typename T, typename... Types>
struct index_of {};

template<typename T, typename... Types>
struct index_of<T, std::tuple<Types...>> {
    static constexpr std::size_t index = []<std::size_t... Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
        return ((std::is_same_v<T, Types> ? Is : 0) + ...);
    }(std::index_sequence_for<Types...>{});
};

template<typename T, typename Tuple>
constexpr std::size_t index_of_v = index_of<T, Tuple>::index;

template<typename T, std::size_t N, typename Tuple>
using next_type = std::tuple_element_t<(index_of_v<T, Tuple> + N) % std::tuple_size_v<Tuple>, Tuple>;

// usage:
using Types = std::tuple<int, double, std::string>;
using TypeA = double;
using TypeB = next_type<TypeA, 1, Types>; // TypeB is std::string
using TypeC = next_type<TypeA, 2, Types>; // TypeC is int
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/W134MeoGb)